# Trying to create a polymorphic relationship with a condition - not sure if this is possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a polymorphic assets relationship which works fine and is defined like this:

```
  has_many :assets, :as => :assetable, :dependent => :destroy
```

but would like something like this

```
  has_many :instore_images, :as => :assetable,  class_name: "Asset", conditions: { is_instore: false }, dependent: destroy
```

The following works but would naturally like to have it as a relationship:

```
  def instore_images
    Asset.where('assetable_type=? and assetable_id=? and is_instore=true','MenuItem', self.id)
  end
```

The error I get is:

```
/Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `assetable' for #<Class:0x007fd85ed71ea8> (NameError)
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible and, if yes, what would the syntax be?

### Edit #1 asset model

Not that much there but:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assetable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :id, :is_instore, :asset_file_name, :asset_content_type, :asset_file_size, :asset_updated_at,
  require 'digest/md5'
  
  default_scope :order => 'position'
  acts_as_list :order => 'position'
```

Comment: Can you post your `asset` model?